# How to get Id from Kendo check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, checkbox, kendo-ui

I have used Kendo Template as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(x => x.RateBand.IsChecked)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { ng_element = "$rateBandIsChecked" })
    .Label(LocalizedStrings.IsChecked)
    .Enable(!Model.RateBand.IsChecked)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "rateBandEdit_IsCheckedChanged()" }))
```

on the JS or angular module, i need to access this check box.

_ Edit ____

on Inspect view, shows as follows. pls advice.

```
Id = "RateBand_IsPublished"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set the id in the attributes?

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { ng_element = "$rateBandIsChecked", id = "myCheckbox" })
```

Then target it in JS:

```
$("#myCheckbox");
```